# emptyDir in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Very simple question, where is the `emptyDir` located in my minikube VM? Since the `emptyDir` volume is pod dependent, it should exist on the VM  otherwise it will die with a container exiting. When I do `minikube ssh` I cannot locate the volume. I need to inspect it and see if my containers are behaving how I want them to, copying some files to the volume mounted on them. Trying `find / -type d -name cached` results in many `permission denied`s and the volume is not in the rest of the dirs. My `YAML` has the following part:

```
...
volumes:
    - name: cached
      emptyDir: {}
```

and also commands in a container where the container copies some files to the volume:

```
containers:
    - name: plum
      image: plumsempy/plum
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
      args: ["mkdir /plum/cached"]
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /plum/cached
          name: cahced
      command: ["bin/sh/", "-c"]
      args: ["cp /plum/prune/cert.crt /plume/cached/"]
```

The container naturally exists after doing its job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to see if your containers are behaving is by logging in into the container using the kubectl command.

That said: The location should of **emptyDir** should be in **/var/lib/kubelet/pods/{podid}/volumes/kubernetes.io~empty-dir/** on the given node where your pod is running.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I ended up doing, there are strict permission issues every step of the pods/; I had to `sudo chmod o+x /var/lib/kubelet/pods` and `cd pods` and `sudo chmod -R 0755 .` I find this information useful. Would you want to append it to http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#emptydir ? I could do it as well if you don't want to for whatever reason.

Comment: It is strange that you had to change the permissions. I would regard this as a bug in minikube. An issue ticket with such content in github would be more appropriate (I am becoming a bulk bug poster for kubernetes :) ). Which version of minikube is this? Then I will post the bug.

Comment: I added the location in the documentation. It will take a few days before it shows up (if at all)